# Waiting for move in Windows Phone C#

Tags: c#, time, windows-phone, wait

I am writting in Windows Phone a short game noughts and crosses  and I have a problem with waiting for move. I don't really get how to insist a programme to wait for the player's move, I have a code for that part:

```
public void game()
{
    while (!checkResult())
    {
        autoEvent.WaitOne();
        compMove();
    }
}
```

And in that way I have an error after choosing one field `NullReferenceException`. 
I started to changing it to `this.Invoke(compMove());` but it also failed.

Any idea?

Comment: Perhaps you should look into [Event Driven Programming](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C-Sharp-Fundamentals-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Understanding-Event-Driven-Programming-23)

Comment: Thanks, I'm starting to watch it :)

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the windows phone capabilities under event driven programming, but if that isn't possible, then your while loop is the way to go. I'd be tempted to tell you to use a normal windows phone app instead of a Windows Game app. But it really depends on what you want to learn.

Comment: I went wrong, I'm writting a Windows App, not Windows Game (easier) and void game is just the most important function of the code :)

Comment: I don't get it. If it's not game project (DirectX, XNA), you don't have to do anything. Application will be in idle mode and will simply wait for events. I guess that player move is just pressing a button. This will fire an event you have to catch and handle. You don't have to actively wait.

Comment: this is so easy... And I spent half of a day of thinking... Thanks xD